# A question on Lie bracket

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am reading the [note](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ewangzuoq/Courses/16S-RiemGeom/Notes/Lec12.pdf) and get confused with some computation in there.

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. Let $f: [a,b]\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M$ is a smooth map.

Denote $f_{s} := \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial s}$ and $f_{t} := \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$. So these are vector files along the image of $f$.

Then he claimed that $\nabla_{f_{s}}f_{t} = \nabla_{f_{t}}f_{s}$.

At this point I am confused with what definitions of $\nabla_{f_{s}}f_{t}$ and $\nabla_{f_{t}}f_{s}$ are.

In the proof he wrote that
$$\nabla_{f_{s}}f_{t} - \nabla_{f_{t}}f_{s} = [f_s,f_t].\quad (\star)$$

Since we assume the torsion is free, I guess that ($\star$) comes from this.

Question: the torsion tensor is defined over smooth vector fields on $M$, how to define the torsion over $f_s,f_t$, which are only vector fields along the image of $f$.

He then wrote that
$$[f_s,f_t] = df[\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}].$$

Question: why do we have this formula? How to define the Lie bracket of two vector fields along the image of $f$ only?

Comment: To do it properly, you pull back $TM$ along $f$.  To do it lazily, you extend $f_s,f_t$ arbitrarily.

Comment: @ user10354138 Could you give more hint? Do you mean that we can define connection over vector field along the image of any smooth function $f$?